# Dynamic imports not working with Webpack 4 + React + @loadable/component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, code-splitting, dynamic-import

I have a project that uses React with Webpack 4, Babel and TypeScript. I'm trying to have code splitting and installed `@loadable/component` for that. Unfortunately when I call `loadable(() => import(...))` to get one of my pages in a different chunk, webpack or babel doesn't seem to recognize that, nothing happens and I keep with a single JS file. Searched docs, other questions at S.O but nothing seems to work =\

Here's my `.tsx` file:

```js
import loadable from "@loadable/component";

const TextDisplayPage = loadable(() => import("./pages/textDisplayPage"));

const AppRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route
      exact
      path="/introduction"
      render={() => (
        <TextDisplayPage
          textsToDisplay={DisplayTexts.INTRODUCTION}
          continueButtonLinkURL="/character"
        />
      )}
    />
  </Switch>
);
```

My `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@loadable/babel-plugin", "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

Part of my `webpack.config.js` file (don't know if that's enough information but if it's not just let me know) :

```js
/*...*/
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: ["babel-loader", "ts-loader"],
      }
    ]
/*...*/
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know you only have one js file? Are you calling webpack to bundle it? If so, are you running it in production mode?

Comment: Yes I'm calling webpack. Tried to run in development and production mode but none worked

Comment: Can you also share your `babel` configuration? It would be even better in case of having working example as well

Comment: @SirPedr is your `module` set to `esnext` in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: It's kinda awkward  but I stoped working on this for a while and forgot about that question. Now I started to code on this and my `module` was not `esnext`, and fixing that plus changing `target` in `webpack.config.js` to `web`  solved the problem. Thanks!